# Errors Using yaml-cpp Library in ROS

Tags: ros, yaml-cpp, yaml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, I'm using ROS Fuerte and trying to use yaml parsing in my program. I have a "include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>" in my code but I am still getting errors. According to the ROS wiki, I should not need to change my CMakelists.txt or manifest.xml to use it but I still get errors like :

> /home/aramus/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/image_test/src/image_test.cpp:54: undefined reference to YAML::Node::Node()'
> /home/aramus/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/image_test/src/image_test.cpp:92: undefined reference to YAML::Node::~Node()'
> /home/aramus/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/image_test/src/image_test.cpp:92: undefined reference to YAML::Parser::~Parser()'
> /home/aramus/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/image_test/src/image_test.cpp:92: undefined reference to YAML::Node::~Node()'
> /home/aramus/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/image_test/src/image_test.cpp:92: undefined reference to YAML::Parser::~Parser()'
> /home/aramus/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/image_test/src/image_test.cpp:92: undefined reference to YAML::Node::~Node()'
> /home/aramus/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/image_test/src/image_test.cpp:92: undefined reference to YAML::Parser::~Parser()'

Any help on how to fix this would be great. Thanks!

EDIT:
I fixed it by adding
rosbuild_add_executable(image_test src/image_test.cpp)
target_link_library(${PROJECT_NAME} yaml-cpp)

I originally had the two switched around but order matters a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60037/errors-using-yaml-cpp-library-in-ros/) by [joshualan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4617/joshualan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2013-04-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2013-04-05**:
Please include your CMakeLists.txt file and manifest.txt .

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2013-04-05**:
Can you include the ROS wiki link that specified that you shouldn't need to change your CMakeLists.txt or manifest.xml to use yaml-cpp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you didn't link your node against the `yaml-cpp` library. See the [documentation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/yaml_cpp) for how to do that in Electric and newer.

In a nutshell you probably need to add something like:
`target_link_libraries(image_test yaml-cpp)` to your CMakeLists.txt .

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2013-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't provide much code for diagnosing this problem.

The correct header reference should be:

```
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>
```

Your manifest.xml should include:

```
  <rosdep name="yaml-cpp"/>
```

Check those for a start.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-04-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1